# Python does not identify json dictionary keys and writes it twice. (Discord.py)

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I've been trying to open a json file store the items into a variable, modify/add one item, and then dump it back to the json file. This works, but when I open the file again it does not identify the key.

```py
with open("descriptions.json", "r+") as f:
    descs = json.load(f)
descs[ctx.guild.id] = desc
with open("descriptions.json", "w+") as f:
    json.dump(descs, f)
embed = discord.Embed(
    title="Description Set", 
    description=f"Your server description is set!\n{desc}", 
    color=0x13f30f
)
await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

This is the code at the moment. When I use the command to set a description it works all fine. Using it again will NOT replace the value of the key (which in this case is the id of the server), but create another key with the same name and put the description there. Note that even if I use the same description, it will still not work.

**Using it for the first time**

```
{"452945790697078785": "Test Description"}
```

**Using it for the second time**

```
{"452945790697078785": "Test Description", 452945790697078785: "Test Description"}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Seeing a little more of the code may help us help you.

Comment: Running `print(repr(list(descs.keys())))` just before `json.dump`ing should show all keys in a helpful manner to find out more.

Comment: I just tried using `print(repr(list(descs.keys()))`
Here is it:
`['452945790697078785', 452945790697078785]`

Comment: One key is an int, one is a string. You must convert one to the other. Probably `ctx.guild.id` is an int which should be converted to a string.

Comment: Thanks so much... I just did and it fixed. Thank you <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically using `print(repr(list(descs.keys())))` showed me that one key was an integer and the other key was a string. Therefore, converting the `ctx.guild.id` to a string fixed the problem.

```
with open("descriptions.json", "r+") as f:
    descs = json.load(f)
descs[str(ctx.guild.id)] = desc
print(repr(list(descs.keys())))
with open("descriptions.json", "w+") as f:
    json.dump(descs, f)
embed = discord.Embed(title="Description Set",
                      description=f"Your server description is set!\n{desc}",
                      color=0x13f30f)
await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```